# Layout run off for different screen size for Android

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, ionic-framework

My app created in ionic 1 framework.
My app with this button created will run off with different sizes of screen.

For a 7 inch screen, the icon and words tend to skew to top.

[image]

for 5 inch, the icon and words tend to skew to bottom

[image]

There are two requirements:

1. The icon and words centered for all the screen sizes (inside the six aquares boxes).
2. When the screen size is larger, the icon/words looks larger while when the screen smaller the words and icons to be smaller. The reason is the 6 square that contains icon/words will be depends on the screen size.

Below is my code

html

```
 <div id="row2" class="row">
    <a class="col">
      <div class="colwrapper">
        <i class="material-icons">&#xE06D;</i>
        <span>Watchlist</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="col">
      <div class="colwrapper">
        <i class="material-icons">&#xE8B6;</i>
        <span>Search</span>
      </div>
    <a class="col">
      <div class="colwrapper">
        <i class="ion-stats-bars"></i>
        <span>Top Movers</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="row3" class="row">
    <a class="col">
      <div class="colwrapper">
        <i class="icon ion-medkit"></i>
        <span>Portfolio Diagnosis</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="col" >
      <div class="colwrapper">
        <i class="material-icons">&#xE152;</i>
        <span>Screener</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="col">
      <div class="colwrapper">
        <i class="material-icons">&#xE417;</i>
        <span>Snapshot</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

css

```
#row2 .col .colwrapper, #row3 .col .colwrapper{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 55%;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
#row2 .col .colwrapper i, #row3 .col .colwrapper i{
  font-size: 30px;
}
#row2 .col img, #row3 .col img{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 75%;
  width: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
#row2 .col span, #row3 .col span{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: use media queries for font size and flexbox for centering

Comment: @mehulmpt could you elaborate more? In css or html?

Comment: media queries in CSS can be used to identify different sized devices (in CSS). flexbox layout will allow you to center text among all. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @mehulmpt No, flexbox does not take effect on ionic 1. Not sure why